# Django follower structure with manytomany field unable to display in Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Here is my follower model:

```
class SocialProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)
```

In Admin:

```
class SocialprofileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = SocialProfile.follows.through
```

The above admin code in admin will give me:
An overall view:

[image]
Inside each profile:

[image]

I just need it to display username instead of SocialProfile object. 
I tried a few version like this but they are not working:

```
class FollowsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SocialProfile.follows.through


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'follows')
    inlines = [FollowsInline, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [display a human-readable representation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#str) you should write a `__str__` (if using python2 the name should be `__unicode__`) method on the model. Django admin will use this method to display the instances, you don't need to override or customize anything in *admin.py* for this.

In your case, like this:

```
class SocialProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return human-readable representation"""
        return self.user.username
```